# Youtube not playing above 360p

Tags: firefox, youtube

I finally switched to using Ubuntu a few days ago and so far it is great! The only issue I am having is that YouTube doesn't play above 360p. The options above it are not showing. It shouldn't be that the hardware is too slow as I have a Radeon R9 280x and an AMD FX8350. My internet connection is also plenty fast enough download being 100Mbps and upload being 20Mbps. The only thing that I could figure is that YouTube is using the HTML5 player which doesn't work with Firefox properly.

Comment: You are using Firefox? Youtube probably used HTML5 on windows too, so that should not be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try `mv ~/.mozilla/ ~/.mozilla.old/` which pretty much resets your firefox to see if it helps.

Undo using `mv ~/.mozilla.old/ ~/.mozilla/` if it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/html5?gl=DE) and select the HTML5 player to be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue with codec like shown in image:

[image]

You could enable `Media Source Exntension` by following steps.

To enable these in Firefox, do the following:

1. Type about:config into the web browser's address bar and hit enter.
2. Confirm that you will be careful if a warning message is displayed.
3. Search for media.mediasource.enabled and double-click the name to enable.
4. media.mediasource.mp4.enabled to true
5. media.fragmented-mp4.* to true
6. media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder to false

Answer (score 0):

1.In the address bar enter **about**:**support**
 then **reset firefox**
Comment your result